# Error in my Constraint Script = "With"

Tags: sql-server

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_SLD] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([SLD_ID] ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,  
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY], 
 CONSTRAINT [USLD_NKEY] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
 (
    [P_TYP] ASC 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
```

I'm trying to write a constraint in SQL and I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you specified a table for this constraint to be added to, you are missing a closing ')' after your second constraint's column name, and I am not sure where your 3rd 'On [Primary]' is being used.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_SLD] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([SLD_ID] ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY], 
 CONSTRAINT [USLD_NKEY] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
 (
    [P_TYP] ASC 
   ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

 GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there is a larger create table script above this.  That I didn't include in the original question.

Comment: Well then its with your 2nd contraint.  No closing ')' after the column name.  Updated code. And do you need 3 'on [Primary]' statements?